# XML content still ISO 8859-1 after UTF-8 JAXB Marshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, apache-camel, marshalling

I'am using camel to create a JAXB object, marshall it and write then the result in UTF-8 encoded XML file.
Some of my xml content is fetched from a datasource which is using an ISO 8859-1 encoding:

hier is my camel route:

```
import org.apache.camel.converter.jaxb.JaxbDataFormat;

JaxbDataFormat jaxbDataFormat = new JaxbDataFormat(Claz.class.getPackage().getName());

from("endpoint")

   .process(//createObjectBySettingTheDataFromSource)

   .marshal(jaxbDataFormat)

   .to(FILEENDPOINT?charset=utf-8&fileName=" +Filename);
```

The XML is generated successfully, but the data content fetched from the source still in the ISO encoding and not resolved with UTF8.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>     
     <Name>M��e Faࠥnder</Name> //Mürthe Faßender
```

by changing the file encoding to ISO 8859-1 the content is resolved successfully.

I tried to convert the data before setting it in the JAXB object but still not resolved in UTF-8.

```
  byte[] nameBytes = name.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
  return new String(nameBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

The problem is only accuring under Linux, does any one have an idea how to manipulate the ISO_8859_1 data and set it without issues in the xml ?

Comment: I had a similar problem with the charset related to double conversion: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10053 not sure if it apply here, I used `.removeProperty(Exchange.CHARSET_NAME)` to avoid the double charset change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, **UTF-8 is the default charset** (at least for the file endpoint) and AFAIK Camel does not try to analyze the given charset of an input message.

So I guess that if you **don't declare an input charset different than UTF-8** and then write a file as UTF-8 there is **no need to convert** anything from Camels perspective.

```
.from("file:inbox") // implicit UTF-8
.to("file:outbox?charset=utf-8") // same charset, no conversion needed
```

You can, at least for files, declare the source encoding so that Camel knows it must convert the payload.

```
.from("file:inbox?charset=iso-8859-1") 
.to("file:outbox?charset=utf-8") // conversion needed
```

If you cannot declare the input charset (I think this depends on the endpoint type), you have to explicitly convert the payload.

```
.from("file:inbox") 
.convertBodyTo(byte[].class, "utf-8")
// message body is now a byte array and written to file as is
.to("file:outbox")
```

See the section "Using charset" from the [Camel File docs](https://camel.apache.org/file2.html) for more details.

Comment: hi burki, i'am writing in the file the result of the marshalling object with setting some data from an ISO_8859_1 source, the marshaller itself is with utf-8 encoding. converting the body to utf-8 is not olving rhe problem.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you mean you only put **some** ISO encoded "data fragments" into an XML file that is already UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: yes, i'am generating an xml file with the result of the marshalling of my JAXB object. some of the JAXB object attribute are containing an ISO encoded attributes.

Comment: Well then you have to convert these information bits by yourself. You can instruct Camel to convert a whole message payload, but not small parts of a payload. How should it know what to convert and what to leave as is? However, you can of course write a Bean that does these specific conversions and use it as a Processor in your Camel route.